# Using a timer while running a process visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

My timer stops running when a process is started, how can I keep the timer going untill the process finishes, I had this working before so I'm really confused why it stopped working.

```
    Timer1.Start()
    Dim p As New Process
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\db.bat"
    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
    TabControl1.SelectTab(3)
```

I think I need to run the process slightly differently but I still need to keep wait for exit as this moves on to the next tab.

Comment: WaitForExit presumably blocks the ui thread so there are no more timer events until it returns, run your process from another thread

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** block the main thread of a GUI program.  Use the Process.Exited event instead.  Also use p.SynchronizingObject = Me so you don't fight threading.

Comment: I think a combination of a New thread and a Process.Exited event would be the answer to this, I have managed to get the timer back but my tab3 now gets cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my final solution to this was to run a new process in a background worker, which was running async to my form, when run worker complete it selected the next tab.

This video was really helpful for understanding workers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMIOVVLhUvE